# selenium server problem

Tags: eclipse, selenium

In eclipse i write one test case  i am trying to run that case but its showing error
This is my sample test case with junit:

public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
        seleniumServer.start();
        selenium.start();
    }

```
public void testCase1() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/jaidproj/home.jsp");
    selenium.click("//ul[@id='navigation']/li[2]/a/span[2]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("//div[@id='sidebar-a']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a[3]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("//ul[@id='navigation']/li[4]/a/span[2]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("//ul[@id='navigation']/li[5]/a/span[2]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("name", "dsagasg");
    selenium.type("email", "jaid.sk@gmail.com");
    selenium.type("contact", "342532235");
    selenium.type("comment", "sdfsagasgas");
    selenium.click("submit");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
}


public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
```

}

//
i updated in java build path jar files also..

But at the run time its showing error:see the error below

****Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444****
can any one help in this regard.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Post more info.  Like a full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Close the session of server once you finish executing testcases by typing the below line in browser

http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

Comment: Agree on this one.. Make sure to close the server after each run. Or make it easier for your self. Start a Selenium Server from a command prompt and let it run. By this you will avoid troubleshooting problems with the server if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Mozilla firefox is not on path.Please set and you can successfully run your tests..

Comment: its sucess ful for 1st test case at the time of running second test case showing same error.... whats the exact prblm.....